# primary key in the same order after updating the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I've a table with two columns: first one contains id (from 1 to 10) and the second column contains sales. I sorted the sales column in desc order. After doing that, I would like to see the Id column in the same order (from 1 to 10). How do i do that? Thanks in advance.(I'm using Microsoft sql server btw)
I did forget to mention that I want to see this in a new table. I mean in the new table, sales will be in the desc order with new Ids (from 1 to 10). Sorry to mention that. thanks.

Comment: Why? There's no reason to re-order rows.

Comment: You want to sort one column and not the rest of data?

Comment: Perhaps you could include DDL, sample data and expected results to make it a bit more clear what you are asking?  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id, Sales, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sales DESC)
FROM table
ORDER BY sales DESC
```

Comment: Hi , Add some comments to your answer, high light script and cntrl+K to align the script

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by sales desc) id, sales from yourtable order by sales desc --id is order and sale in desc order
```